# Is it possible to send a Whatsapp message from Mathematica?

Tags: webservices

Just as the question reads.

The only way I could think of this working is if one could interface with the Whatsapp web app.

The motivation is to simply alert me when simulations or batch routines have finished.

Comment: What about sending a good ol' email instead? That definitely works. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SendingEmail.html

Comment: Sure!! There's nothing really wrong with using email, I just A) wanted to see if it can be done, and B) I don't tend to use email on my phone so much, so WhatsApp is a little more convenient.

Comment: In principle, you can send WhatsApp messages using the Twilio API https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api that you could drive either using the Twilio Service https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/Twilio.html or through plain-old REST.  For a deep dive on price, and how-to tutorials see: https://rocketbots.io/blog/whatsapp-business-api/

Comment: If there's an API (which @JoshuaSchrier says there is) then the answer is definitively yes. At one point here I wrote up a few tutorials on using the built-in Mathematica stuff to make API connections. Might be worth looking that up.

Comment: Related: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1672156